# Does hosting images on a CDN impact SEO?

Tags: seo, cdn

I manage two sites (foo.com and bar.com) which share image assets. Currently the images are all on the foo.com domain which is a bit confusing if you open the image on bar.com and see a foo.com URL.

I'd like to have a generic domain for these shared resources and I'm planning on using Rackspace Cloud Files (which [can plug into the Akamai CDN](http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge%5fcenter/product-faq/cloud-files)) so that we can also benefit from increased performance.

My question is, if we use the Rackspace Cloud Files URLs (e.g. [http://c0344252.cdn.cloudfiles.rackspacecloud.com/cute_kids.jpg](http://c0344252.cdn.cloudfiles.rackspacecloud.com/cute%5fkids.jpg)) what (if any) impact will it have on the SEO performance of foo.com.

Position within Google Image search is of minimal importance to us so I'm particularly interested in any knock-on impact for Web search performance.

Comment: Using a CDN improves the loading speed of your pages and thus SEO of these pages.

Comment: There are also many other questions and answers already on Pro Webmasters relating to the usage of a CDN, the benefits and seo value > http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?q=CDN+SEO+is%3Aquestion